# Convert string to slice of string

Tags: go, yaml

**TLDR**
How to convert `"[\"a\",\"b\"]"` (type string) to slice of string `["a", "b"]`?

**Usecase**
I am using text/template to create a yaml file which is used in go package.

```
// test_params.yaml
ips: {{.ips}}
```

```
// values.yaml
ips: '["10.0.0.1","10.0.0.2"]'           # string
```

```
// get_ip.go

// Read values
v, _ := ioutil.ReadFile("values.yaml")
config = make(map[string]interface{})
_ = yaml.Unmarshal(v, &config)

// Create file and replace values
tmpl, _ := template.New("CentralConfig").Parse(tmplStr)
f, _ := os.Create("final_yaml.yaml")
_ = tmpl.Execute(f, config)
```

This will create a yaml

```
// final_yaml.yaml
ips: '["10.0.0.1","10.0.0.2"]'           # string
```

From where I have to use `ips` as `[]string`.

The reason I am not using an array in the first place in `values.yaml` is that it will create `final_yaml.yaml` that is not proper yaml.
So if I had used

```
// values.yaml
ips: ["10.0.0.1","10.0.0.2"]           # array
```

then the final_yaml would look like:

```
// final_yaml.yaml
ips: '[10.0.0.1 10.0.0.2]'           # string
```

which doesn't seem usable at all.
Also, if someone has a better approach to do the same something to use variables in yaml (maybe like a library yaml/template similar to text/template), I would be pleased to hear.

Comment: That input looks like JSON. If it is, just unmarshal it.

Comment: I thought so too. https://play.golang.org/p/q6wsbMtiBFu Am I making a mistake here?

Comment: Ohh, right! I shouldn't marshal it first. Thanks!

Comment: Your input is already marshaled. You need to unmarshal it.

Answer (score 0):

From the YAML perspective, the sensible thing to do would be to give the value as sequence and then properly render it out again. go-yaml allows you to capture the YAML structure as `yaml.Node` however it is not able to convert it back to a string representation again. Given the data in `yaml.Node`, it is generally possible to implement it yourself for simple input:

```golang
package main

import (
    "gopkg.in/yaml.v3"
    "os"
    "text/template"
)

var testParams = `ips: {{.ips}}`

var params = `ips: ["10.0.0.1","10.0.0.2"]`

type Subtree struct {
    root *yaml.Node
}

// UnmarshalYAML is called by the YAML unmarshaler and captures
// the value as yaml.Node.
func (s *Subtree) UnmarshalYAML(n *yaml.Node) error {
    s.root = n
    return nil
}

func renderNode(n *yaml.Node) string {
    switch n.Kind {
    case yaml.ScalarNode:
        return "\"" + n.Value + "\""
    case yaml.SequenceNode:
        ret := "["
        first := true
        for _, item := range(n.Content) {
            if first {
                first = false
            } else {
                ret += ", "
            }
            ret += renderNode(item)
        }
        return ret + "]"
    default:
        panic("node kind not implemented")
    }
}

// String is called by the template renderer.
func (s *Subtree) String() string {
    return renderNode(s.root)
}


func main() {
    var config map[string]*Subtree
    _ = yaml.Unmarshal([]byte(params), &config)

    tmpl, _ := template.New("CentralConfig").Parse(testParams)
    _ = tmpl.Execute(os.Stdout, config)
}
```

This will render

```
ips: ["10.0.0.1", "10.0.0.2"]
```

Please be aware that `renderNode` as given is **not** safe as it will not properly escape special characters in scalars. Also it doesn't handle mappings or aliases. This snippet merely serves as starting point and you'll need to add additional functionality as necessary.